# How can i solve this error "type object 'User' has no attribute 'object'"

Tags: django

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import auth

def signup(request):
    if request.method =='POST' :
        if request.POST['password1'] == request.POST['password2']:
            user = User.object.create_user( 
                username=request.POST['username'], 
                password=request.POST['password1'])
            auth.login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
    return render(request, 'signup.html')
```

this is my code.
when i try to sign up, my code makes this error page
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrpCw.png)

where's the angel? Help me plz

Comment: I have nothin in models.py. Am I have to make 'User class' in models.py?

Answer (score 0):

It is `objects` not `object`. Watch out for typos (-:

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the line `user = User.object.create_user(username=request.POST['username'],password=request.POST['password1'])`.... change this line to `user = User.objects.create_user(username=request.POST['username'],password=request.POST['password1'])`.